# Why can't I instantiate an instance of an extended class in Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, static, extends

What I'm simply trying to do is extending a class from LinkedList. Here is my code:

```
  import java.util.*;

  class Test {

    public static void main( String [] args ) {

        OrderedLinkedList ol = new OrderedLinkedList();
    }

    public class OrderedLinkedList extends LinkedList<Integer> {

        public boolean add( Integer item ) {
            for (int i=0; i < size(); i++) {
                Integer itemOfList = get( i );
                if ( itemOfList.compareTo( item ) > 0 ) {
                    add( i, item );
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

However, I got compile error with this message:

```
Test.java:7: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        OrderedLinkedList ol = new OrderedLinkedList();
                               ^
1 error
```

I believe I'm not referencing anything but instantiating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An inner class has an implicit reference to its outer class, unless marked static.

You need to mark the inner class static to avoid this:

```
public static class OrderedLinkedList extends LinkedList<Integer> {
```

So the compiler is complaining that there isn't an instance of Test for the inner class as main is a static method.

Answer (score 1):

1) Close Test class 
 2) If you are having both classes in same file,
    main class should be the file name and only main class should be
    public.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main( String [] args ) {

        OrderedLinkedList ol = new OrderedLinkedList();
    }
}
```

Then

```
class OrderedLinkedList extends LinkedList<Integer> {

            public boolean add( Integer item ) {
                for (int i=0; i < size(); i++) {
                    Integer itemOfList = get( i );
                    if ( itemOfList.compareTo( item ) > 0 ) {
                        add( i, item );
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

IF Inner class is your requirement, then make your class as static class

Comment: The `OrderedLinkList` in the original question is an inner class. As an inner class, it is placed correctly.

Comment: @JanDvorak: If that is the case, make inner class as static. From question it is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the two classes in separate files. However if an inner class was your goal then

access it as follows

```
new Test().new OrderedLinkedList();
```

Comment: This syntax is unknown to me. Reference?

Answer (score 0):

Your class `OrderedLinkedList` is not in static context. Please  change  `public class OrderedLinkedList extends LinkedList<Integer>` to  `public static class OrderedLinkedList extends LinkedList<Integer>` and compile it should do. A reading on static and instance variables would help to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare ol as static:

```
static OrderedLinkedList ol = new OrderedLinkedList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you implementing a `public` class `OrderedLinkedList` inside another class `Test`?

Move your inner class in its own file. It should work.